# Visual Studio 2017, The diagnostic tools failed unexpectedly. Output "Unzulässige Funktion" (invalid function)

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017, diagnostics, diagnostics-hub

When i start the C++ debugger, the "Diagnostic Tools" windows shows this error.
"The diagnostic tools failed unexpectedly."
The output windows shows

```
"Unzulässige Funktion." 
"Unzulässige Funktion."
```

It doesn`t matter what project i open, the error is still there

My windows is set to german language, my visual studio is english.
I tried to change the language of visual studio also to german to match the language of windows, but the error was still there just in german.

I tried also uninstalling and installing of the modules "C++ Profiling" and "Test tools for core features" with the Visula Studio Installer.

Also a repair run with the Visual Studio Installer didn`t help.

Comment: Wayyyyy too little information to be able to help you. Please give a [mcve].

Comment: I can´t give an example, the error is not specific to the c++ project. It doesn`t matter what project i open, the error is still there. It seems that the VS2017 installation is somehow broken. I tried also uninstalling and installing of "C++ Profiling" and  "Test tools for core features". Maybe i have to uninstall and install the whole VS2017.

Comment: Unrelated: Do you have to use VS2017? If you are not forced to use that version, do a fresh installation of VS2019.

Comment: O.T.: _I tried to change the language of visual studio also to german to match the language of windows_ I've used various versions of VS with the default lang. choice (German also in my case) for years and always struggled to communicate my issues or fix suggestions in sites like e.g. this one. Recently, I installed a brand-new VS2019 and, this time, I forced it to English. I immediately noticed that googling issues became much easier... ;-)

Answer (score 0):

The almost unbelievable solution was to change the environment variable `TEMP` from `R:\Temp` back to the standard path `C:\WINDOWS\TEMP`.
(`R:` is a RAM disk.)

Comment: you don't want to use ram drive for %TEMP% location, ever! Installers use that path for downloading, saving logs, saving semaphore files or intermediary state, sometimes that requires restart and files will vanish...breaking your installation. That's how updates  sometimes manage to brick Windows. If an application can work with volatile cache, it usually would have own setting to point at the preferable location.

Comment: I am glad you have got your solution and thanks for your sharing, I would appreciate it if you mark them as answer and this will be beneficial to other community.